# Building a conversational model using TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I'd like to build a conversational modal that can predict a sentence using the previous sentences using TensorFlow LSTMs . The example provided in TensorFlow tutorial can be used to predict the next word in a sentence .

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/v0.6.0/tutorials/recurrent/index.html

```py
lstm = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
# Initial state of the LSTM memory.
state = tf.zeros([batch_size, lstm.state_size])

loss = 0.0
for current_batch_of_words in words_in_dataset:
    # The value of state is updated after processing each batch of words.
    output, state = lstm(current_batch_of_words, state)

    # The LSTM output can be used to make next word predictions
    logits = tf.matmul(output, softmax_w) + softmax_b
    probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    loss += loss_function(probabilities, target_words)
```

Can I use the same technique to predict the next sentence ? Is there any working example on how to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the [Sequence-to-sequence](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/seq2seq/index.html#sequence-to-sequence-models) model. Instead of having it learn to translate sentences from a source language to a target language you have it learn responses to previous utterances in the conversation.

You can adapt the example seq2seq model in tensorflow by using the analogy that the source language 'English' is your set of previous sentences and target language 'French' are your response sentences.

In theory you could use the basic LSTM you were looking at by concatenating your training examples with a special symbol like this:

`hello there ! __RESPONSE hi , how can i help ?`

Then during testing you run it forward with a sequence up to and including the __RESPONSE symbol and the LSTM can carry it the rest of the way.

However, the seq2seq model above should be much more accurate and powerful because it had a separate encoder / decoder and includes an attention mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

A sentence is composed words, so you can indeed predict the next sentence by predicting words sequentially. There are models, such as the one described in [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.07998) paper, that build embeddings for entire paragraphs, which can be useful for your purpose. Of course there is [Neural Conversational Model](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.05869) work that probably directly fits your need. TensorFlow doesn't ship with working examples of these models, but the recurrent models that come with TensorFlow should give you a good starting point for implementing them.

Comment: Thanks Keveman, Actually I was looking for any working sample to get me started .